# Android TTS text longer than 4k chars not playing

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am using `TextToSpeech` to play some long texts sometimes, and I have noticed that since `Android 4.1.2` if the text is longer than 4000 chars, it does not play.

I do not get any errors, but the text won't be played. Until now I was able to reproduce this just on `Android 4.1.2`(Samsung Galaxy Nexus, Nexus7).

Is this a bug just in `4.1.2` or is this normal (although I did not find any documentation regarding this behaviour)?

Also I have found a post : [onUtteranceCompleted() lost if TTS received is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863107/onutterancecompleted-lost-if-tts-received-is-too-long) which indicates different problems with texts longer than 4000 chars.

**EDIT:** I tried to split my string in 4k length chunks, and send it to `TTS` using `QUEUE_ADD` and I came across another [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482899/android-jelly-bean-tts-queue-add-does-not-work): `QUEUE_ADD` does not work, instead it flushes the existing queue, and only the last chunk gets played.

**EDIT2** : this is my call to `TTS`

```
mTTS.speak(longText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Comment: what's the api call to pass the string? maybe the android source code can explain more

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MAX_SPEECH_ITEM_CHAR_LENGTH = 4000 in TtsService.java,  on 4.1 I see a warn in the code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        if (mText == null) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Got null text");
            return false;
        }
        if (mText.length() >= MAX_SPEECH_ITEM_CHAR_LENGTH) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Text too long: " + mText.length() + " chars");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

looks like 2.3 splits the text instead, so teorically your code should work on android < 4.1 and not on newer (I don't known when the split was removed), instead you have the opposite :) that is a bit strange

Comment: here is the code http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/eyes-free/com/google/tts/TTSService.java.htm

Comment: at least strange( this is not documented). and also QUEUE_ADD does not work... so I can not play longer texts on >4.1...

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to use [`onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html) to know when the first chunk has finished, and then, feed the next chunk to `TextToSpeech` until they are all finished.

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) { //On TTS init
    //guava Splitter
    mChunks=Lists.newLinkedList(Splitter.fixedLength(3999).split(mExtractedText));
    mTTS.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
    playNextChunk();
}

private void playNextChunk(){
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, ""+mChunks.size());
    mTTS.speak(mChunks.poll(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
}

@Override
public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
    playNextChunk();
}
```

Comment: dude i have 10k+ character,so tts will work first 4k only,after finished the 4k,it wants to start the next 4k like that it has to do.How to do that.i cant get your code logic dude.

Answer (score 3):

No problem on 4.4.2... I split my Strings like this...

```
//textToSpeech can only cope with Strings with < 4000 characters
int dividerLimit = 3900;
if(textForReading.length() >= dividerLimit) {
    int textLength = textForReading.length();
    ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count = textLength / dividerLimit + ((textLength % dividerLimit == 0) ? 0 : 1);
    int start = 0;
    int end = textForReading.indexOf(" ", dividerLimit);
    for(int i = 1; i<=count; i++) {
        texts.add(textForReading.substring(start, end));
        start = end;
        if((start + dividerLimit) < textLength) {
            end = textForReading.indexOf(" ", start + dividerLimit);
        } else {
            end = textLength;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<texts.size(); i++) {
        textToSpeech.speak(texts.get(i), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }
} else {
    textToSpeech.speak(textForReading, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```